# Shiny Reactive SQL: WHERE clause

Tags: sql, oracle, shiny

I am new to SQL and i am trying to figure out how i can "select all" in WHERE clause.

Let me make it bit more clearer why i would like to achieve that:

I do have reactive SQL in my Shiny App. The user can filter at least three different variables in my SQL:
[image]

In this case user can choose Kunde (Customer), Abmessung (Diameter) and Date. I do have hard time to figure out when the user wants to filter only one/two variables and not three (the combinations of possibilities inside is huge, and writing SQL Query in if statement for each is quite a thing). So for example the user would like to have Kunde (Customer) filtered but all the Abmessung (Diameters) kept.

Here is a sample SQL Query which i have used:

```
select * from x.xy where kdname IN (",paste0("'",paste(input$kunde, 
collapse="', '"),"'"),") and abmessung IN (",paste0("'",paste(input$abm,
collapse="', '"),"'"),") and dati_create between
to_date('",format(input$date[1], '%d.%m.%Y'),"','dd.mm.yyyy') and
to_date('",format(input$date[2], '%d.%m.%Y'),"','dd.mm.yyyy') + (86399/86400)
```

Is there a possibility in SQL to use some kind of "*" in WHERE clause?

Comment: Check the updated version of my answer. Though, you definitely should provide sample user input and expected results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not simply do it using if to each condition and than paste collapse it

( i think there isn t way to do what your want without "if\esle" or "case" or "nvl" or "decode" so you need to hardcode it)

like:

```
input=list("kunde"="a","abm"="b",date=c("2016-01-01","2016-02-01"))
#input=list("kunde"="","abm"="",date=c("","")) # for test
sql_main="select * from x.xy "
sql_cond=list()
sql_cond[1]=  if(input$kunde==""){NULL}else{paste0("kdname IN ('",paste(input$kunde,collapse="','"),"')")}
sql_cond[2]=  if(input$abm==""){NULL}else{paste0("abmessung IN ('",paste(input$abm,collapse="', '"),"')")}
sql_cond[3]=  if(input$date[1]==""|input$date[2]==""){NULL}else{paste0("dati_create between to_date('",as.character(as.Date(input$date[1]),'%d.%m.%Y'),"','dd.mm.yyyy') and
to_date('",as.character(as.Date(input$date[2]),'%d.%m.%Y'),"','dd.mm.yyyy') + (86399/86400)")}
sql_cond=sql_cond[!sapply(sql_cond,is.null)]# needed to del NULL in list
sql_cond_all=paste(sql_cond,collapse  =" and ")

sql=if(sql_cond_all!=""){paste(sql_main,"where",sql_cond_all)}else{sql_main}
sql
```

Comment: Nice way of doing it, however i have tested it quite deeply and if only one/two conditions is/are choosen, the `sql_cond_all=paste(sql_cond,collapse  =" and ")` is empty and i cannot figure out why as it is stated in `sql_cond[1]=  if(input$kunde==""){NULL}else...`

Comment: i have just checked it and used the code to check null in list. However it is not about the NULL, the list `sql_cond` just does not appear (it is empty) if only one of the arguments is choosen and comes an error: `Error in if: Argument hat Länge 0`. When all the arguments are choosen it works just fine

Comment: I cant reproduce your error ... save you input as data.frame using `<<-`and post it dput

Comment: I have found the error, it was on the side of `sql_cond[1]=  if(input$kunde==""){NULL}...` and exactly the part: `input$kunde==""`. I had to create new choice in input$kunde called in my case "Alle" (all) and then when i have changed the argument if(input$kunde=="Alle"){NULL}...` , sql worked perfectly. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with shiny. However, I think you could achieve your goal by using oracle's `decode` function.

The `where` clause will look something like this (pseudo-code)

```
        where 
         decode(input_variable,null,1,input_variable)=decode(input_variable,null,1,table_column)       
         and dati_create between 
             decode(input_date1,null,'1/1/1900',input_date1)         
         and decode(input_date2,null,'1/1/3000',input_date2) 

         and table_column2 in (
         SELECT decode(inputvarable2,null,  (select  table_column2 from dual) 
,TRIM(REGEXP_SUBSTR(temp, '[^,]+', 1, level)) )  

    FROM (SELECT  inputvarable2 temp FROM DUAL)

    CONNECT BY level <= REGEXP_COUNT(temp, '[^,]+')
    )
```

Here I assume that when input variable is not given - it has `null` value. Also, as user input sample was not provided, I assume that user input for `in` clause is comma separated string. (e.g. 'a,b,c')

And thus, if `input_variable` is `null` then `where` becomes `1=1` (always `true`), otherwise it is `input_variable=table_column`. With dates it is a little bit more tricky - so I give very early date (`1/1/1900`), or very far away one (`1/1/3000`). The logic behind `in` clause, is to convert user input into `collection` from comma separated string and then use the same trick with `decode`.

Though this might not be the most efficient way to do this.

Also I see that you are concatenating user input directly into your sql statement. This is highly risky - as your code would be prone to   [sql injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! ok, that seems reasonable but concatenating of the user input (where ... IN(...)) is necessary--> in Your code i cannot see where i can put it

Comment: @Malvina_a could you provide an example of user inputs, so that, maybe, I could adjust my solution...

Answer (score 0):

If you use `RMySQL` you can just paste together a chr string as query.
So you could do something like this:

```
condition <- character()

if(input$kdname != "") condition <- append(condition, paste0("kdname IN '", paste(input$kdname, collapse = "', '"), "'"))

if(input$abm != "") condition <- append(condition, paste0("abmessung IN '", paste(input$abm, collapse = "', '"), "'"))

query <- paste("SELECT * FROM x.xy WHERE", paste(condition, collapse = " AND "))
```

Comment: `RMySQL` is for **MySQL*  not for Oracle

Comment: if both input ==""  you get error because of "where" without conditions

Comment: Oh yeah I didn't see the Oracle tag. Anyway you can always do create a string and then execute it with `parse()` and `eval()`. Not very nice, but it works. If both inputs `== ""` you would add another condition with `WHERE` only being added if `condition` not empty. This was just an example.

Comment: Interesting way, however it is not working well, Your code takes into account only 1st condition

Answer (score 0):

I find `sub` function very useful when constructing queries, try this:

```
myquery <- 'select * from x.xy where kdname IN "NAME" and abmessung IN "ABM" and dati_create between DATE1 and DATE2 + (86399/86400)'
date1 <- input$date[1];date1 <- sub("-",".",date1);date1 <- sub("-",".",date1)
date2 <- input$date[2];date2 <- sub("-",".",date2);date2 <- sub("-",".",date2)
myquery <- sub("DATE1",date1,myquery)
myquery <- sub("DATE2",date2,myquery)
myquery <- sub("NAME",input$kunde,myquery)
myquery <- sub("ABM",input$abm,myquery)
myquery <- noquote(myquery)
myquery
```

Comment: Hey, unfortunatelly it did not work for me, only different errors occured, as: `Invalid procedure call or argument on Replace function`

Comment: why dont you just write the query you want in SQL, and I will modify it to suit your needs

Comment: Great!Thanks for help, here it is: `select * from x.xy where dati_create between to_date(' 01.01.2016 ','dd.mm.yyyy') and to_date(' 30.08.2016 ','dd.mm.yyyy') + (86399/86400) and kdname IN ('abc', 'def') and abmessung IN (40)` --> it is just an example sql